# I'm not understanding this question. (Gram-schmidt)

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Let $\beta = \{1 − x, 2x + x^2 , 3 + 2x^2 \}$ be a basis of $P_2$ (the vector space of the polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2.

In $P_2$ consider the inner product
$< u, v >= a_0b_0 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_2$

where $u = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ and $v = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2$ are two vectors from $P_2$.

a) Verify that the basis $\beta$ is orthogonal to this inner product.

b) Find an orthogonal basis for $P_2$, according to the inner product presented.

c) Find an orthonormal basis for $P_2$, according to the inner product presented.

Comment: As suggested in the title, use : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_process

Comment: Please verify that I did not make a mistake when editing your question: are the polynomials in the basis $\beta$ the ones you wrote?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: I've corrected a typo in the equation $u=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$, where $a_1$ had previously been $a-1$. But there's a more serious problem: Contrary to part (a) of the question, $\beta$ is not orthogonal with respect to this inner product. That's probably a good thing, because if (a) were correct then (b) would be trivial --- just copy $\beta$.  I suppose the OP might have omitted "not" from the statement of part (a).

Comment: Sincerely thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calculations we obtain: $$<1-x,2x+x^2>=-2\ne 0\\<3+2x^2,2x+x^2>=2\ne 0\\<1-x,3+2x^2>=3\ne 0$$which is not orthogonal.

A basis which is both orthogonal and orthonormal is $\{1,x,x^2\}$

Comment: How did you make this inner product?

Comment: @MagnoAugusto By applying the definition.